# example of a normal proper flat scheme over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

The lecture today began, "Let $X$ be a normal, proper, flat scheme over $\mathbb{Z}$, with $\dim X = 2$ and $X(\mathbb{C})$ is smooth" This lecture is way too advanced.

- Wikipedia's definition of **[normal scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_scheme)** is "that the local ring at the point is an integrally closed domain. "
- I was unable to find the definition of "proper scheme" and could only find **[proper morphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_morphism)**
- I could find **[flat morphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_morphism)** but not flat scheme
- A **[smooth scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_scheme)** is  well approximated by affine space near any point.  I only know about smooth manifolds.

Therefore I am reading that part of all of his reasoning will break down for any realistic example.

The only example I could think of is a circle $x^2 + y^2 - 1$ since it is an example for everything.

Comment: If you don't know what any of these things mean then you're likely out of your depth. However, here is a rule of thumb for properties of schemes: we define properties of **morphisms**, then we say a scheme over $S$ has this property if the morphism $X\to S$ has this property.

In the case being considered, every scheme (i.e a scheme over $\Bbb Z$) has a natural, unique morphism $X\to\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Z$. That is, $\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Z$ is the terminal object in the category of schemes. We say $X$ has a property $P$ if the morphism $X\to\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Z$ has property $P$.

Comment: @SheafKeef $\mathrm{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$ is just the prime numbers, right?  So how do we map a 2D scheme to the primes?

Comment: By going in the other direction.  Giving a morphism of schemes of $X$ into $\textrm{Spec } \mathbb{Z}$ is the same as giving a ring homomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$ into the ring $\mathcal O_X(X)$.  There is only one possible choice.

Comment: Incidentally, the circle is not an example; it fails to be proper. (Proper roughly means projective, but is more general.)

Comment: @SheafKeef regardless of schemes being way over my head, I still have to do it

Comment: @cactus314 why don't you take a projective space?

Comment: @Rüdiger anything.  I hope the question makes clear I really have no idea.  The lecture is on the ABC conjecture but I don't know enough material about schemes

Comment: @cactus314 In that case you should learn about schemes first (there is not a lot to explain) and come back and refine your question